# Cannot resolve TabLayout

Tags: android

Im trying to use TabLayout in my project but I'm unable to import TabLayout class in my project please help me.
here is the code.

build.graddle

```
 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

}

ive added android.material:material:1.0.0" also by referring the previous question but it didnt work out for me.

here is my xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top">


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

actually i was following a tutorial in youtube and it was working for him but not for me.

here is my java class.

```
package Home;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabLayout; //TabLayout showing red color.`enter code 
here`

import com.example.footag.R;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 0;
private Context mContext = HomeActivity.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
    setupViewPager();
}

private  void setupViewPager(){
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CameraFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);// TabLayout showing red color.
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you perform 2 steps.

Step 1. 
Migrate to the new AndroidX library instead of using AppCompat library. Use **Refactor** → **Migrate to AndroidX**. It will replace your dependencies with AndroidX analogs.

Step 2.
Use `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` dependency to get `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` class. Use this class in your xml and java files. Package name of `ViewPager` will be `androidx.viewpager.widget`.

Example of xml with imports form AndroidX library:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or your import might be incorrect. Try this

```
package Home;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
```